How to enable keyring_file on replication server MySQL?
I recently activated the keyring_file plugin on my master server (5.7.44-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log), so the replication server presented errors when trying to execute alter table xxxxxx encryption = 'Y'
How can I activate this plugin on the replication server (5.7.44-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log) so that both use this encryption method?
